# Render Flex application components asynchronously

Tags: apache-flex

We have Flex application where performance is very important. We have 5-6 tabs in the screen that is taking 10-15 seconds to render the application. Is there any way in Flex where we can render first tab and other tabs should render asynchronously so that user can see first tab and other tabs get loaded in background.

Answer (score 0):

You could delay rendering of not displayed tabs by using [creationPolicy="auto"](http://help.adobe.com/en_US/flex/using/WS2db454920e96a9e51e63e3d11c0bf69084-7cb8.html).

Or you could set `creationPolicy="none"` and instantiate tabs manually with [createDeferredContent()](http://help.adobe.com/en_US/flex/using/WS2db454920e96a9e51e63e3d11c0bf69084-7aee.html) method.